# Why some update notifications do not disappear?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Early there was this notification:

> Tools for Universal Windows Apps (1.1.1) and Windows SDK (10.0.10240)

When I start it 'Update' button is disabled.

Now after update I have the same story with

> Clang with Microsoft CodeGen (July 2016)

Sure, it's not critical, but very annoying.

Comment: having exactly the same issue. I guess Microsoft will fix it after some time.

Answer (score 1):

Its because the Clang update is not applying properly.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2959066/clang-with-microsoft-codegen-july-2016

If you looks closely: You'll be on 14.0.25317, and the new version will be 14.0.25411. I have been trying to update for hours and the new version will not apply. Even did a clean install of VS2015.

Comment: That issues is closed. Active is: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2958869/clang-with-microsoft-codegen-july-2016-not-recognized-as-installed